# How to reload a react component after an update using redux and hooks

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js

I have this next.js page

```
const Index: NextPage = () => {
    const state = useSelector((state) => state);

    useEffect(() => {
        //here we call the api to retrieve the list of comments
        // and we use a useState hook to set the data
    }, []);

        return (
            <>
                <PageHead/>
                <Header/>

                <Container fluid className="page-content">
                    <Row>
                        <Col className="page-content-comments">
                            <Comments comments={data.comments}/>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Container>

                <Container fluid className="page-content">
                    <Row>
                        <Col className="page-content-comments">
                            <CommentForm/>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Container>

                <Footer/>
            </>
        );
};
```

and a Comments component

```
const Comments = (props) => {

    const getComments = (comments) => {
        return comments.map((comment, commentIndex) => {
            return (
                        <li>{comment.text}</li> 
            );
        })
    };

    return (
        <ul>
            {getComments(props.comments)}
        </ul>
    );

}
```

this page loads a list of comments from the DB, and pass them to the Comments component. The CommentForm component is just a form to submit a comment. This part works. Also the CommentForm dispatches a redux event and I can see the updated value in the page (using the useSelector hook).

What I would like to do is to reload the list of the comments when a new comment is created.

I was thinking that maybe the api call should be in a useEffect inside the Comments component? How can I setup it to activate the reload? What is the best practice in this case?

I don't want to reload the page, only the comments list.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use `comments` props as state in `Comments` component and update it each time props changes like this inside `Comments` component

```
useEffect(() => {
    setComments(commentProps)
}, [commentProps])
```

Comments component

```
const Comments = (props) => {
   const [commentsState, setCommentsState] = useState([]);
   
   useEffect(() => {
        setCommentsState(props?.comments)
   }, [props])

    return (
        <ul>
            {commentsState?.map((comment, commentIndex) => (
                        <li>{comment.text}</li> 
            );
        )}
        </ul>
    );
}
```

Comment: I amm not sure how to do this, can you provide a more specific example please? I updated the question with the Comments component.

Comment: If you can share other components or codesandbox, I can give you clear solution @user3174311

Comment: updated with the Comments component.

Comment: I updated my answer, i removed the function getComments but you can add again as well @user3174311

Comment: I am probably missing something. This displays the list of comments but when I insert a new one nothing happens.

Comment: Check your Index component to be sure that you set your data each time you add new comment, normally this should work

Comment: this is probably what I need to do and I don't know how. How can I execute the api call once again when there is a new message?

Comment: I am almost there. If I pass "state" to the useEffect in the next.js page, when state changes useEffect is executed again. However in this way the whole next page is refreshed. How can I refresh the Comments component only?

Comment: Could you please create a codesandbox sample with your components then for sure i can fix the missing part. In this way i can not find your error @user3174311

Comment: no worries I found a way, thanks anyway.